# I want connect metamask how do i do that to browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, plugins, account, metamask

Cant connect tried to didnt work,
Tried wallet connect Tru options i couldnt get it done.
Tried to do it with update next to Chrome also didnt work, please help me.
Does someone have maybe have some advice for me.
Am not exactly good at coding at 0the moment but put a lot of efford and time in to learn.
Werking hard to learn coding and blockchain smart contract and stuff